# How to get difference between Associate arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, compare, associative-array

I have an arrays like this

```
Array
(
    [original_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => 122
                    [id] => 121
                    [reference_name] => Dinesh
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => 123
                    [id] => 120
                    [reference_name] => Dinesh Test
                )

        )

    [edited_data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => 123
                    [id] => 120
                    [reference_name] => Dinesh Test2
                )

        )

)
```

I want to get the difference between this `original_data` and `edited_data` arrays. How to do that? I tried using `array_diff`. But, It didn't work correctly.

Comment: what output you want? please specify.

Comment: @JainamShah the output needs to be [0] => Array
                (
                    [reference_id] => 123
                    [id] => 120
                    [reference_name] => Balasuresh Test
                )

Comment: Currently that's is just: $data['edited_data'].  What do you mean by difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the difference =>

```
$result = ref_array_diff($requestedData['edited_data'], $requestedData['data']);

print_r($result);

function ref_array_diff($arraya, $arrayb) {
    foreach ($arraya as $keya => $valuea) {
        if (in_array($valuea, $arrayb)) {
            unset($arraya[$keya]);
        }
    }
    return $arraya;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `array_map` on both original data and edited data to get an array of original_data id values and edited_data id values. You can then use array_diff with no problem. Using the resulting list of id's which are in one but not the other you can lookup the original value using the array mapped values index key on the original arrays.

I'm making the assumption here that your id key is a unique identifier for each value in the data arrays. If this isn't the case you'll need to do some nested loops to compare deep values

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
<?php

// your data
$data = array (
    'original_data' => array
        ('0' => array
            (
                'reference_id' => 122,
                'id' => 121,
                'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh,'
            ),

         '1' => array
            (
                'reference_id' => 123,
                'id' => 120,
                'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh',
            ),
        ),

    'edited_data' => array
        ('0' => array
            (
               'reference_id' => 123,
               'id' => 120,
               'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh Test',
            ),
        )

) ;


// let's get our reference_ids
$originalData = array() ;
foreach($data['original_data'] as $entry) {
    $originalData[$entry['reference_id']] = $entry ;
}

// let's compare our edited data to our original data
$editedData = array() ;
foreach($data['edited_data'] as $editedEntry) {
    if (isset($originalData[$editedEntry['reference_id']])) {
        // for readability
        $compare = $originalData[$editedEntry['reference_id']] ;
        foreach($editedEntry as $key=>$value) { 
            if ($compare[$key] != $value) {         
                $editedData[$editedEntry['reference_id']][$key] = $value ; 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`$editedData` now contains your differences

Answer (score 0):

These are multi-dimensional associative arrays, you can recursively do an array_diff_assoc like this:
you can check this code here https://3v4l.org/ovaQB:

```
function array_diff_assoc_recursive($array1, $array2)
{
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value)
    {
        if(is_array($value))
        {
            if(!isset($array2[$key]))
            {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            }
            elseif(!is_array($array2[$key]))
            {
                $difference[$key] = $value;
            }
            else
            {
                $new_diff = array_diff_assoc_recursive($value, $array2[$key]);
                if($new_diff != FALSE)
                {
                    $difference[$key] = $new_diff;
                }
            }
        }
        elseif(!isset($array2[$key]) || $array2[$key] != $value)
        {
            $difference[$key] = $value;
        }
    }
    return !isset($difference) ? 0 : $difference;
}

$a=["original_data"=>[
                [
                    'reference_id' => 122,
                    'id' => 121,
                    'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh'
                ],[
                    'reference_id' => 123,
                    'id' => 120,
                    'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh'
                ]

        ],

    'edited_data' => [[
                    'reference_id' => 123,
                    'id' => 120,
                    'reference_name' => 'Balasuresh Test'
                ]]

];

print_r(array_diff_assoc_recursive($a['edited_data'], $a['original_data']));
```

output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [reference_id] => 123
            [id] => 120
            [reference_name] => Balasuresh Test
        )

)
```